# One command to locate source code for a certain rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

First of all, not all tasks are listed by rake -T. But even if I know the task, it's a bear to locate the source code for it. Has anyone written a utility or gem that is kind of like

rake open db:test:prepare

which would open the source file where db:test:prepare is defined into my text editor? With rvm and gemspecs I spend a surprising amount of time hunting around for the right source file.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command displays a comprehensive list, except without the descriptions. Still it is a vast improvement.

```
rake -P | grep rake
```

Reference: http://edgar.tumblr.com/post/29071212872/how-to-list-all-rails-3-rake-tasks

Answer (score 1):

rake -T only lists tasks having a `desc "Foo"` line before them.  Most of the Rails core tasks are defined in `/tasks` subdirectories of various gems (railties being a biggie).

One of the things I like about my IDE (RubyMine) is that it gathers all the gems (which are stored god-knows-where by RVM) into a view within the editor -- I can search, find files, and so on, just as though they were in my normal source path.  And the standard is to put them in a `tasks` subdirectory.

But you probably knew all that, and there's nothing I know of other than rake -T.